# Hibernate sets the update timestamp on save

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity which contains following field

```
   ... 

   @UpdateTimestamp
   @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
   private Date modifiedOn = null;

   ...
```

When I save this entity for the first time, the `modifiedOn` field gets updated too. Shouldn't it keep null as the entity is not modified and saved for the first time.

Comment: Thats just how it works

Comment: Thanks @XtremeBaumer. Any documentation which explains why this is the behavior, I tried to search but couldn't find explanation for it.

Comment: [This forum](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1044342) and [this docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/tuple/GenerationTiming.html)